Android MediaCodec "INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER" logged continuously even with Valid Input
I'm working on an Android application that involves decoding H.264 Tello Drone stream using the MediaCodec API. I've set up a H264Decoder class to handle the decoding process. The decoder is initialized with a SurfaceHolder to render the decoded frames. However, I'm encountering an issue where I consistently receive the "INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER" message, and as a result, my SurfaceView remains black, indicating that no frames are being rendered to it.
Here's my H264Decoder class:
public class H264Decoder {
    private MediaCodec codec;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private long timeoutUs = 20000; // 20 milliseconds timeout
    private long presentationTimeUs = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "H264Decoder";

    public byte[] csd0 = {0, 0, 0, 1, 103, 66, 0, 42, (byte) 149, (byte) 168, 30, 0, (byte) 137, (byte) 249, 102, (byte) 224, 32, 32, 32, 64};
    public byte[] csd1 = {0, 0, 0, 1, 104, (byte) 206, 60, (byte) 128, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, (byte) 229, 1, (byte) 151, (byte) 128};

    public H264Decoder(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        Log.d(TAG, "H264Decoder constructor called");
    }

    public void init() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Initializing H264Decoder");
        try {
            codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
            MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 960, 720);
            format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(csd0));
            format.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(csd1));
            codec.configure(format, surfaceHolder.getSurface(), null, 0);
            codec.start();
            Log.d(TAG, "Codec started");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error initializing codec: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public void decode(byte[] input) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Decoding input of length: " + input.length);
        try {
            int inputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(timeoutUs);
            Log.d(TAG, "Input buffer index: " + inputBufferIndex);
            if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex);
                if (inputBuffer != null) {
                    inputBuffer.clear();
                    inputBuffer.put(input);
                    codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, presentationTimeUs, 0);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Input buffer queued");
                    presentationTimeUs += 1000000 / 25; // Assuming a frame rate of 25fps
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Input buffer is null");
                }
            }

            MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            int outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, timeoutUs);
            while (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
                codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, true);
                outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, timeoutUs);
            }
            if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                Log.w(TAG, "No output buffer available, try again later");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error decoding input: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Releasing H264Decoder");
        try {
            codec.stop();
            codec.release();
            Log.d(TAG, "Codec released");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error releasing codec: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}


I also have a UDPReceiver class which I call to port 11111 (line is in another file) and here is where I create the DatagramSocket
public class UDPReceiver {
    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    private static final String TAG = "UDPReceiver";

    public UDPReceiver(int port) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to create DatagramSocket on port " + port);
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
            Log.d(TAG, "DatagramSocket created successfully on port " + port);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating socket on port " + port + ": " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public byte[] receive() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Waiting to receive packet...");
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        try {
            socket.receive(packet);
            Log.d(TAG, "Packet received. Length: " + packet.getLength() + " bytes from " + packet.getAddress().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error receiving packet: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
        return packet.getData();
    }

    public void close() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Closing DatagramSocket...");
        socket.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "DatagramSocket closed.");
    }
}

I've verified that the input to the decode method is valid H.264 data. Despite this, I keep getting the warning, and no output frames are being rendered to the SurfaceView (it remains black).
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any insights on what might be going wrong here? How can I ensure that the decoded frames are properly rendered to the SurfaceView?
Thank you in advance for your help!
Edit: Thanks to this solution on the Tello Forum http://tellopilots.com/threads/sdk-streamon-format.2809/post-15678, I managed to solve my issue.
The reason I kept on getting INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER is because the Tello drone doesnt send complete frames. Instead, they come in slices of a frame and each one has a packet length of 1460 but eventually there will be one that has a lower packet length which indicates the end of the frame. All I did was basically collect these slices and once I get a complete frame I pass it into the H264 Decoder to decode it and it all worked suddenly.

It seems that you are getting INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER all the time because you call dequeueOutputBuffer in a loop. You shouldn't need a loop since you decode one buffer at at time.

Did you check that surfaceHolder.getSurface() is not null?

Thanks for the help but I was able to solve it!
